# R combine two lists of sfc_polygons

Tags: r, geometry, geometric-arc, r-sf

Hej, 
I have two lists of polygons. 
The first one is a list of 1 polygon (circle)
The second is a list of 260 polygons (260 rectangles).
See the first picture ([two lists of polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcGJr.png)).

Now I want to keep all the rectangles that are touched by the circle.
See picture 2 [merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9lSk.png) and 3 [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7T7I.png).

Does somebody has any idea? There are serveral things. st_combine, st_intersection - but their are not useable for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your blocks are in `a`, and your circle in `b`; have you tried

```
a[lenghts(st_intersects(a, b)) > 0]
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Without a reprex it's hard to give a full answer, but I think you want to use `st_intersects`. This can take two sf objects and return either a list of vectors of pairs that intersect (`sparse = TRUE`) or a full logical matrix of whether those indices intersect (`sparse = FALSE`). In this case, I would use the latter, and then appropriate `filter` to get only the rows you want.